# Error when install with apt-get install

Tags: apt

I faced whit this issue trying to install any package:

```
The dependency tree is built

Status information is read ... Finished

The gimp package is not available, but it is mentioned by another package.
This might mean that the package is missing, has become obsolete, or
Is only available from another source.

E: Package 'gimp' has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: GIMP is in universe now.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be sure to have the universe repository, where the gimp program package is stored, run (in a terminal window)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and if you have an installed system (but *not* if you have a live or persistent live system)

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Finally install gimp with

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```