# Can't install any app in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation

No app can be installed in my system after I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc gimp gparted synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package gimp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package vlc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vlc' has no installation candidate

E: Package 'gimp' has no installation candidate

E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Comment: Hey Yusharth! Please paste the output of `apt-cache policy vlc gimp gparted synaptic` in your question by [edit]ing it. BTW, I suggest you to read this: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you updated your ubuntu from 19.1 to 20.04 or did you do a fresh install?

Also, try this:
[Error when install with apt-get install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928109/error-when-install-with-apt-get-install)

It says that you should have  universe repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and if you have an installed system (but not if you have a live or persistent live system)

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I updated. And apt update and apt-get update is working. But can't install vlc or any other app.